# Ошибка при открытии Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ошибка при открытии Visual Studio 2010

Пишет: Инициализатор типа "Module" выдал исключение.

ОС: Windows 7 64bit

Comment: какая версия фреймворка установлена ?

Comment: Хотел установить .NET Framework 4, установщик пишет: Такая же или более новая версия .NET Framework 4 уже установлена на этом компьютере.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Comment: Установите минимум 4 и ошибки не будет

Comment: пробовал установить которую вы указали, пишет что у меня уже установлен!

Comment: установите последний

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил все программы по имени .NET Framework. Потом установил это: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=17718

После установки открыл сразу Visual Studio 2010, все сработало!